# SPARQL Syntax correction

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

It's my first time using SPARQL.
Using DBpedia, I want to list the band names of all Rock bands from 1992

The code I've already developed runs correctly but gives 0 results. Am I filtering the date incorrectly?

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?bandname where {
?band dbo:genre dbp:Rock_music .
?band foaf:name ?bandname .
FILTER (dbo:activeYearsStartYear >= xsd:date("1992-01-01") && dbo:activeYearsStartYear <= xsd:date("1992-12-31"))
}
```

I expect only the band names in a column.

Comment: `dbo:activeYearsStartYear` is a property in DBpedia, which means you should use it in the predicate prosition of a triple pattern to get the actual values for the property. Like you did for the band name, you also used a property and assigned the values to a variable `?bandname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?bandname ?date where {
?band dbo:genre dbp:Rock_music .
?band foaf:name ?bandname .
?band dbo:activeYearsStartYear ?date .
FILTER (?date >= "1992-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime && ?date <= "1992-12-31"^^xsd:dateTime)
}
```

This does the trick but note that dbo:activeYearsStartYear produces the year only, so FILTER is not using day/month.

Comment: It works Demo : http://linkedwiki.com/query/List_the_band_names_of_all_Rock_bands_from_1992